# Combine a text field with a shape in Sketch - Auto re-size shape

Tags: text, shapes, sketch-app

Is it possible to combine a text field with a shape in Sketch whereby the shape will auto expand to accommodate the text length?

[image]

Comment: Try this plugin: https://github.com/ddwht/sketch-dynamic-button

Answer (score 2):

Sketch doesn't have this functionality built-in by default, but there are two very similar plug-ins that offer it:

- [Dynamic button](https://github.com/ddwht/sketch-dynamic-button)
- [Compo](https://github.com/romashamin/compo-sketch)

I've been using Dynamic button for quite a while, but recently switched to Compo, as it offers greater control in setting margins (e.g. it's possible to keep an element fixed to a certain side of a component).

Comment: FWIW I just tried both of those plugins on symbols in Sketch 50.2 with no luck. They might work on non-symbols, but that defeats the purpose for me as I want to be able to do things like update the design of a variable height list item from one place.

Comment: @Weston Yes, they only work on non-symbols. I don't know of a way to use symbols for this.

Answer (score 1):

A plugin that's definitely working for symbols in Sketch 50.2 is [Paddy](https://github.com/DWilliames/paddy-sketch-plugin). By creating a specially named layer, the plugin will auto-resize it every time the "contents" are resized.

A [newer version](https://github.com/DWilliames/paddy2-beta) is being developed that is much more powerful, too

Answer (score -1):

Aside from plugins, the only workaround would be to duplicate the text layer, convert one of them to outlines and hide the other.

This way you still have a backup to change text if you really need to.
The outlines will scale, but the hidden text won't.